# Upload video on Youtube present on Google Drive using API

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Videos can be uploaded on Youtube, using api as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert?csw=1), and the video that would be uploaded will be present on the **local hard drive**.

I have video uploaded on Google Drive, and want to have it uploaded on the Youtube, using API. Is there a way to achieve it? I can access Google Drive and Youtube using API individually, but unable to find how to connect them.

I believe implementation language won't be required, since we will be consuming APIs, and if required, the implementation has been done in Python.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the file from Google drive using the Google drive api to your local machine. Then upload the file from your machine to YouTube api.

There is no way to upload directly from google drive to YouTube.  Although you might be able to do something with a memory stream so that you dont actually download it to your hard drive.  But its still going to have to run from your machine or a server some place the two apis cant talk to eachother.